# Django admin and MongoDB, possible at all?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, mongodb

I'm building a simple short URL service, ala bitly, for our company use. And I would like to use mongodb to store the data, but I will need some kind of simple interface to add/edit short url to long url mappings.

The mongo documents will be very simple, something like this:

```
{
  shortUrlSlug: 'pbbs',
  fullUrl: 'http://example.com/peanut/butter/and/bacon/sandwiches/'
}
```

Is there anything out there that exposes a simple "CRUD" admin interface to mongodb, that can be integrated with django, where you can specify the model?
Basically like django admin, but without requiring a SQL database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have confirmed that django-nonrel project does support the admin interface. I did have a problem where the default SITE_ID was picked up as a number, which is not allowed as a primary key in MongoDB. I resolved this by setting:

SITE_ID = '4d421623b0207acdc500001d'

in my settings.py

I got the number by printing the id of the first site value in the collection through the shell.

I have not tested this extensively, but did register an admin for a Poll object and see it work.

Comment: This completely works.  Just launch the mongo shell, execute "db.django_site.find()" and use the ObjectId value from the result as the value for SITE_ID in your settings.py.

Comment: If you don't need sites option removing it from installed app does also the job

Answer (score 9):

I have used django-nonrel with [mongodb-engine](https://github.com/django-mongodb-engine/mongodb-engine) and it works well. Django admin also works with standard model fields. But if you are using listfield and dictfield, you would need to do some hacking.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not positive, but django-nonrel and the mongodb backend may support the django admin nowadays... it might be worth looking into

http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel

Answer (score 1):

[django-nonrel](https://github.com/django-nonrel/django) is a fork of django and it hasn't been updated for over a year. [django-mongonaut](https://github.com/jazzband/django-mongonaut) and [django-mongoadmin](https://github.com/klavdijv/django-mongoadmin) are django packages and are probably a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

Django Admin is VERY MUCH possible with MongoDB. Have you looked into the [Djongo](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/) project?

Djongo is a SQL to MongoDB query compiler. It translates every SQL query string into a mongoDB query document. As a result,

- All Django models and related modules work as is.
- Use the Django Admin GUI to add MongoDB embedded documents.
- Djongo provides API extensions to the Django ORM that let you ‘embed’ one document inside another, like MongoEngine.

There is an article on [Using Django with MongoDB](https://medium.com/@SiddyZen/using-django-with-mongodb-by-adding-just-one-line-of-code-c386a298e179) by adding just one line of code, if you are looking for more information. Otherwise, you can jump directly into the [djongo documentation](http://nesdis.github.io/djongo/) and start using it.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but if someone happens to be facing the same problem today, I think his best bet would be http://humongous.io. It's a django-admin like interface for mongoDB. It knows how to guess/deal with relationships and works pretty much as the Django admin.

Answer (score -2):

mongodb has many behaviors and django-admin is for relation database like postgresql

you can create django admin with `django-nonrel` but its not optimize and good. i think its bettwr you create custom admin for your application.