# How to get django admin app working with mongodb?

Tags: python, django, mongodb, mongoengine, django-nonrel

I'm trying to use mongodb together with django. I mainly use the admin app of django. 
I noticed that there are 2 mongodb orms for django.

1. One is mongoengine, https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine
2. Another is mongodb-engine from the django-nonrel group.
   https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine

What I want to know is that whether django's admin app works fine with the two. If not, 
which one is better.

Also, I want to know whether 3rd party apps would work if I use mongodb with django? Which of the two orms is more friendly with 3rd party apps?

At first glance, mongodb-engine seems to be more friendly, but it depends on django-nonrel, 
which is based on django 1.5. If I want to use recent version of django, mongoengine seems to be the better choice, also mongoengine development seems more active.

Comment: Why don't you just try? Asking opinions on "which one is better" is never going to be a question that hangs around here.

Comment: I want to know what is working on django if using mongodb.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is yes. Django works well with MongoDB.

Please check this thread for more relevant answers: [On Using Django with MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506809/django-admin-and-mongodb-possible-at-all)

Hope it helps.